# how to get the url chain to be encoded by regex?

Tags: cross-domain

i am have postMessage by http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

```
var url= "http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FDefault.aspx";
$.postMessage({ if_height: $('body').outerHeight( true ), urlframe: url }, parent_url, parent );
```

How to get urlframe with receiveMessage ?

Comment: Can you please provide more information?  It does not seem clear what results you are trying to achieve.

Comment: you to see this page http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-postmessage/examples/iframe/

Comment: The parent window code Ben took the if_height with var h = Number( e.data.replace( /.*if_height=(\d+)(?:&|$)/, '$1' ) ); in $.receiveMessage.
I add one more parameter outgoing side postMessage is urlframe and I did not know how to get it